# Generalizations of results on the sum of divisors function over $\mathbb{Q}$ to number fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider the sum of divisor function
$$
\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} 1.
$$
This is known to satisfy $\sum_{n\leq x} \sigma_0(n) = (x\log x)+2\gamma x+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$.  If, instead, we shift the setting to a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the analogous sum 
$$
\sigma_0(\mathfrak{n}) =\sum_{\mathfrak{d}\mid \mathfrak{n}} N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{d}),
$$
what can be said about the sum
$$
\sum_{N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{n})\leq x} \sigma_0(\mathfrak{n})?
$$
What about the related function
$$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} 2^{\omega(d)}$$
where $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime divisors of $n$, but considered in the context of a number field $K$.  In particular, what's the main term of
$$
\sum_{N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{n})\leq x}\sum_{\mathfrak{d}\mid \mathfrak{n}} 2^{\omega(\mathfrak{d})}
$$
I'd be happy with a reference.

**Edit:** I accidentally started with $\sigma_1$ when I meant $\sigma_0$.

**Edit 2:** In response to @sea turtles comment, what if we restrict to a totally real field?

Comment: your first claim "satisfy" is impossible. Hardy and Wright, Theorem 324, $$ \sigma(1) + \cdots + \sigma(n) = \frac{\pi^2 n^2}{12} + O(n \log n)  $$ In any case,  $$ \sigma(1) + \cdots + \sigma(n) \geq 1 + \cdots + n = \frac{ n^2 + n}{2}   $$

Comment: Alright, Theorem 320, $$ d(1) + \cdots + d(n) = n \log n + (2 \gamma - 1)n + O(\sqrt n)  $$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors on $n$

Comment: $2 \gamma - 1.$

Comment: If $|{\cal O}_K^\times|=\infty$ then these sums are infinite. Over ${\cal O}_{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb Z$ we have the luxury of specifying positive divisors but what do you plan to do in an arbitrary number field? Perhaps you should be counting not just elements but *associates classes* of elements.